# Subject-verb agreement

Tags: grammaticality

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> We learn that environment shape civilization and influence liturature.

Or

> We learn that environment shape***s*** civilization and influence***s*** literature.

I'm confused if the verbs, "shape" and "influence" need to agree with the word, "environment."  In microsoft grammar-check, both versions seem to be correct.

Comment: @jwpat7 Fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Microsoft is a computer software house, not an English teacher. "Environment" is a singular noun and should have singular verbs.

> Environment shapes civilisation and influences literature.

...is a complete sentence and can be considered in isolation. Then, when you make it what is learnt:

> We learn that environment shapes civilisation and influences literature.

...it must remain the same. It's possible that the software is getting confused by the initial *we* and not recognising the difference the *that* makes.